# Problem to insert in SQLite3 from PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I have strange problem on PHP page, I am trying to insert new row to table users (SQLite3) like this

```
 $id=$db->insert_user("'".$parameters['first_name']."'", "'".$parameters['last_name']."'", "'".$parameters['email']."'", "'".$parameters['username']."'", "'".$parameters['password']."'", "'".$parameters['privilege']."'");
```

where

```
     try {
            $db = new SQLite3($this->db_path);

           echo "INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,username,password,privilege) VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$username','$password','$privilege');";
           $db->query("INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,username,password,privilege) VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$username','$password','$privilege');");

            $last_id = $db->lastInsertRowID();
            echo ''.$last_id;
            $db->close();
            return $last_id;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Exception caught: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }

INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,username,password,privilege) VALUES(''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''ignore'');
```

result from echo is

```
INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,username,password,privilege) VALUES(''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''ignore'');
```

Error message is strange, it says in line 35, but 35 is in switch and I never pass through 35, have breaks. Does anybody have some clue what is wrong ? (all columns are ok and table name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the sql query, there is `''drkosh''`, but there should only be `'drkosh'`

```
INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,username,password,privilege) VALUES(''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''drkosh'',''ignore'');
```

try this:

```
$id=$db->insert_user($parameters['first_name'], $parameters['last_name'], $parameters['email'], $parameters['username'], $parameters['password'], $parameters['privilege']);
```